# Is it possible sending notification without any file in Kaa platform?

Tags: curl, notifications, kaa

All Kaa notification samples, including curl, used file approach to send notification data. Is it possible to send notification data just by parsing Json object to string and send it as a body just like updating configurations? I do not want to my notification body first saved to my hard drive. then curl read from that file. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Curl provides command-line data parsing (argument -d). See [curl man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)
Example:

```
    curl -v -S -u username:password -X POST \
    --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \ 
    --header 'Accept: application/json' \
    -d '{"id": "42", "name":"kaa_notification"}' \
    'http://localhost:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendNotification' | python -mjson.tool
```

UPD: See also [REST API documentation](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Server-REST-APIs/).

Comment: I have such curl command:   
`
curl -v -S -u devuser:devuser123 -F'notification={"applicationId":"2","schemaId":"196608","topicId":"1","type":"USER"};type=application/json' -F'endpointKeyHash=vS2G8STv+37hNP6n2jP8FOnbSMI=;type=text/plain' -F file=@/home/ehsan/Desktop/myNotif.json "http://localhost:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendUnicastNotification" | python -mjson.tool
`    And I have no Idea how to send notification part of request. could you please make me informed about the whole command.

Comment: #Y. Verzun
'
curl -v -S -u devuser:devuser123 -X POST \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
-d'{"notification":{\"applicationId\":\"2\",\"schemaId\":\"196608\",\"topicId\":\"1\",\"type\":\"USER\"}' \
-d'{"endpointKeyHash":"vS2G8STv+37hNP6n2jP8FOnbSMI=;type=text/plain"}' \
-d '{"file":""{\"name\":\"gl\",\"source\":\"gl.mp3\",\"type\":\"file\",\"volume\":\"20\",\"priority\":\"1\",\"action\":\"play\",\"start_time\":\"10:21\",\"stop_time\":\"10:23\"}"}' \
"http://localhost:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendUnicastNotification"|python -mjson.tool
'

Comment: any suggestion would be appreciate
my request says **"upload completely sent off: 361 out of 361 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error"**

Comment: I deleted ";type=tex‌​t/plain" from endpointKeyHash same result